# Remove characters before character "."

Tags: c#

How effectively remove all character in string that placed before character "."?

*Input:*
**Amerika.USA**

*Output:*
**USA**

Comment: Is there always only going to be one period?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can use the [`IndexOf` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd(v=VS.100).aspx) and the [`Substring` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx) like so:

```
string output = input.Substring(input.IndexOf('.') + 1);
```

The above doesn't have error handling, so if a period doesn't exist in the input string, it will present problems.

Comment: @casperOne Actually doesn't IndexOf return -1 if not found, and strings are zerobased for reference of substring, so technically if there were no period it would return the whole string, right? I think this is sufficient so long as the string is not null.

Comment: @drachenstern: IndexOf will return -1 if not found, and if that is passed to Substring, it will throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Comment: @casperOne ~ tut tut, its -1 `+ 1` ... so it'll be zero or more, always. Your code not mine ;)

Comment: @drachenstern: Duh, yes, correct.  It will give you the whole string in this case.

Comment: @casperOne ~ hehehe, I had to read it thrice before I caught it too, just a little pen and paper exercise to pass the time, yeah?

Comment: @drachenstern: Yep, but it's one of those things that if you aren't careful, it will bite you. Good catch!

Answer (score 32):

You could try this:

```
string input = "lala.bla";
output = input.Split('.').Last();
```

Comment: You'll have issues if there's more than one 1 period.

Comment: @MikeCole Why? .Last() will make sure you get the last word after a period

Comment: @CaioProiete because OP is asking to remove characters before a period where we assume there'll only be one period in given string. The answer is correct given this assumption. Otherwise it is ambiguous.

Comment: string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Last'

Comment: @CaioProiete Say the input string contains more than one full stop (period) - e.g. `A.B.C`. Your answer would give `C` (characters up to _last_ full stop removed) while the OP may want `B.C` (characters up to _first_ full stop removed). It's not entirely clear though as the OP seems to assume the input string contains only one full stop.

Comment: @Ruben9922 OP seems to want to capture `C` and not `B.C` given his question and example. It seems he has a hierarchy delimited by dots. Your `A.B.C` example as a hierarchy would be something like `PlanetEarth.America.USA`. He likely would still want to capture the last item in the hierarchy: `USA`

Answer (score 12):

```
string input = "America.USA"
string output = input.Substring(input.IndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
String input = ....;
int index = input.IndexOf('.');
if(index >= 0)
{
    return input.Substring(index + 1);
}
```

This will return the new word.

Answer (score 6):

Extension methods I commonly use to solve this problem:

```
public static string RemoveAfter(this string value, string character)
    {
        int index = value.IndexOf(character);
        if (index > 0)
        {
            value = value.Substring(0, index);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static string RemoveBefore(this string value, string character)
    {
        int index = value.IndexOf(character);
        if (index > 0)
        {
            value = value.Substring(index + 1);
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: All `if` clauses should actually be: `if (index >= 0) ...`

Answer (score 4):

```
public string RemoveCharactersBeforeDot(string s)
{
 string splitted=s.Split('.');
 return splitted[splitted.Length-1]
}
```

Comment: Side note: This results in retaining both (or all) parts of the dotted string which is desirable if you need all of them but unneeded if you only ever need the last one.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of methods that, if the char does not exists, return the original string.

This one cuts the string after the first occurrence of the pivot:

```
public static string truncateStringAfterChar(string input, char pivot){         
    int index = input.IndexOf(pivot);   
    if(index >= 0) {
        return input.Substring(index + 1);          
    }           
    return input;       
}
```

This one instead cuts the string after the last occurrence of the pivot:

```
public static string truncateStringAfterLastChar(string input, char pivot){         
    return input.Split(pivot).Last();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following extension methods for cropping everything before or after a given character token.

I also have the same methods for string token, but I won't post them here to avoid cluttering.

**PS**: The cropping of the token can be controlled with the optional paramater.

```
public static string CropAfterFirst(this string str, char searchToken, bool cropSearchTokenToo = true)
{
    int index = str?.IndexOf(searchToken) ?? -1;
    return index < 0 ? str : str.Substring(0, cropSearchTokenToo ? index : ++index);
}

public static string CropBeforeFirst(this string str, char searchToken, bool cropSearchTokenToo = true)
{
    int index = str?.IndexOf(searchToken) ?? -1;
    return index < 0 ? str : str.Substring(cropSearchTokenToo ? ++index : index);
}

public static string CropAfterLast(this string str, char searchToken, bool cropSearchTokenToo = true)
{
    int index = str?.LastIndexOf(searchToken) ?? -1;
    return index < 0 ? str : str.Substring(0, cropSearchTokenToo ? index : ++index);
}

public static string CropBeforeLast(this string str, char searchToken, bool cropSearchTokenToo = true)
{
    int index = str?.LastIndexOf(searchToken) ?? -1;
    return index < 0 ? str : str.Substring(cropSearchTokenToo ? ++index : index);
}
```

The answer for the OP's question is:

```
// Removes everything before the last dot, including the dot itself:
string output = input.CropBeforeLast('.');

// Removes everything before the first dot, including the dot itself:
string output = input.CropBeforeFirst('.');
```